# Passing Argument to MATLAB Function in Python Results in Error: Size inputs must be numeric

Tags: python, matlab

I'm currently working on a python script that passes an argument to a function `getWeight.m` written in MATLAB.

`getWeight.m` returns a weight matrix with the same dimensions given the size of an RGB image. It's source code can be found [here](https://github.com/kluo8128/cs231_project/blob/master/code/getWeight.m).

I'm running the following python script:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()

import cv2

image = cv2.imread('warped_image.png')

weight = eng.getWeight(image.shape) # (575, 503, 3)
print(weight)
```

Passing `image.shape` of class `tuple` as an argument to the function yields the following error:

`Size inputs must be numeric`

Are there any workarounds to this error?

Here's the error after following @Chris method:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    weight = eng.getWeight(matlab.int8(list(image.shape))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matlab/
mlarray.py", line 106, in __init__
    raise ex
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matlab/
mlarray.py", line 104, in __init__
    super(int8, self).__init__('b', initializer, size, is_complex)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matlab/
_internal/mlarray_sequence.py", line 57, in __init__
    self._data = flat(self, initializer, init_dims, typecode)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matlab/
_internal/mlarray_sequence.py", line 338, in flat
    return array.array(typecode, nested_list)
OverflowError: signed char is greater than maximum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out how matlab converts python types: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/pass-data-to-matlab-from-python.html

A python `tuple` will be converted to a matlab `cell array`, so in your `getWeight` function when you access the indeces with `size(3)` you're selecting a cell rather than the value of the cell.

You can change your `getWeight` function to pull out the values of the cells (e.g., `size{3}`) and it should work. If this function is used in many other places you may want to add some checks within `getWeight` to see if `size` is a normal array (when it should use `size(3)`) vs a cell array.

You could also change the input to accept integers instead, e.g., `getWeight(s1,s2,s3)` and then call it with `eng.getWeight(image.shape[0],image.shape[1],image.shape[2])`. But again, if `getWeight` is used elsewhere you'll have to refactor every call.

Finally, you could try converting the tuple to a "matlab numeric array object" and then passing that array to `getWeight`. See the documentation here for how to create a matlab array in python: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-arrays-as-python-variables.html I don't have matlab on my present computer, but I believe the following code would work:

```
import matlab.engine

eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()

import cv2

image = cv2.imread('warped_image.png')

weight = eng.getWeight(matlab.int8(image.shape))
print(weight)
```

The examples of creating the matlab arrays in the matlab documentation all use lists (for example `A = matlab.int8([1,2,3,4,5])`), so you may need to convert that `image.shape` tuple to a list, but I suspect the tuple will work...

Comment: Ran your code and it yielded this error `OverflowError: signed char is greater than maximum`

Comment: can you provide the full stack trace? is the error in the python or the matlab? exactly what line is throwing the error? what is the value of the `image.shape` tuple? Try adding some breakpoints or print statements in the matlab code to see what the `size` variable looks like when it gets passed in. Without matlab I won't be much more use to you, but this is almost definitely just a type conversion issue so you probably just need to step through and look at the values of the arguments outside and within the matlab function.

Comment: However the script when edited works well with `weight = eng.getWeight(image.shape[0],image.shape[1],image.shape[2])`

Comment: ah, the new issue is probably that I suggested `matlab.int8()` (which I just copied from the matlab docs without thinking). Could you try with `matlab.int32()` or `matlab.int64()`?

Comment: I've tried it with `matlab.int32()` and `matlab.int64()` which yields an error `Not Enough Input Arguments`. Despite passing one argument (list or tuple) the error still shows up

Comment: hmm. interesting! I think I'm at the limits of what I can do without matlab myself though. maybe someone else will take it up? but at least the approach with using separate arguments for the different dimensions works for now! you might want to try posting over in the matlab forums too.

Comment: Using separate arguments definitely makes it hard coding and less pythonic I'll try coming up with an alternative to the `getWeight` function and keep you posted